How to create test data now that HKWorkout.init() is deprecated
Now that HKWorkout.init() is deprecated what's the best way to create dummy or test [HKWorkout] data for the Simulator or Xcode Preview?
I'm looking for the simplest way to create an array of [HKWorkout] so I can test some SwiftUI view functionality.
I don't believe that I can use the HKHealthStore() from within Xcode and I'd rather not have to deploy to my iPhone every time I want to test my UI.
Just for context, previously I could do something simple like
// Create a dummy workout
let workout = HKWorkout(activityType: .running,
                        start: workoutStartDate,
                        end: workoutStartDate.addingTimeInterval(duration),
                        duration: duration,
                        totalEnergyBurned: HKQuantity(unit: .kilocalorie(), doubleValue: Double.random(in: 200...500)),
                        totalDistance: HKQuantity(unit: .meter(), doubleValue: distance),
                        metadata: nil)
            
workouts.append(workout)


HKHealthStore can be used from within the Preview and the Health kit authorization screen is also show in the preview. Apparently HKWorkoutBuilder is the way to go.
